# Oracle 11g maximum statement length possible

Tags: oracle, select, limit

I am facing the issue with very long statements in Oracle 11g (~220k-symbol selects with a lot of autogenerated IN (...) clauses). Selects are fired by JDBC causing `SQLException 17410 No more data from socket`.

On the other hand, selects with the same structure but with shorter lengths (~100k symbols) are executed fine.

The problem is that there is no reference in the docs on how to manage maximum statement length. There is just a [note](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits003.htm#i288032): `The limit on how long a SQL statement can be depends on many factors, including database configuration, disk space, and memory` which is not informative at all.

Can anyone share an experience on how to estimate this maximum length and what database tweaks (if any) can help to increase it?

Comment: Are you sure it's related to the length? Could the longer statement just be taking so long to execute that the connection is dropped by SQL\*Net or a firewall, say? Or does the server alert log show an error occurring? If it is length, can you supply the `IN` clauses as collection parameters instead, which would also be easier to manage on the Java side?

Comment: I am not sure its about the length itself, looks more like some big-length side-effect. Thanks, ill try to check for DB logs to get clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Having thousands of expressions in `IN (...)` seems to be a bad design. Better insert such values into a (temporary) table and limit the result by JOIN or `IN (SELECT ...)`

Anyway, the statement length is almost unlimited. I have an application where I run large statements like this:

```
DECLARE
   cmd DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2A;
   cur INTEGER := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
   res INTEGER;
BEGIN
   cmd(1) := 'INSERT INTO';
   cmd(cmd.LAST+1) := 'some columns, ';
   cmd(cmd.LAST+1) := 'and some more,'; -- each line is limited to 32767 chars

   DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cur, cmd, cmd.FIRST, cmd.LAST, TRUE, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE); 
   res := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(cur);
   DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cur);

END;
```

Note, `DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE` does not fetch any data. For `SELECT` the procedure would be

```
DECLARE
   cmd DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2A;
   cur INTEGER := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
   res INTEGER;

   refCur SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   cmd(1) := 'SELECT ';
   cmd(cmd.LAST+1) := 'some columns, ';
   cmd(cmd.LAST+1) := 'and some more,'; -- each line is limited to 32767 chars

   DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cur, cmd, cmd.FIRST, cmd.LAST, TRUE, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE); 
   res := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(cur);
   refCur := DBMS_SQL.TO_REFCURSOR(cur);
   FETCH refCur BULK COLLECT INTO ...;

   CLOSE refCur;

END;
```

or use `DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE_AND_FETCH` if you prefer. Procedure `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT` may also help.

So far I never faced any limitation with this method.

Comment: Agree with bad design, unfortunately its a huge legacy piece i am not sure i can refactor safely. I am mostly confused with the documentation note in my first post which is very confusing and blurred